# Remove file extensions using htaccess in subdirectories

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove file extensions with htaccess, so `www.mysite.com/file.php` becomes `www.mysite.com/file`.

I'm using the following code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So far, so good. Where it falls down is in subfolders: **www.mysite.com/subfolder/file.php**
becomes **www.mysite.com/file**.

I've tried uploading another `.htaccess` file in the subfolder, but it still does the same. It feels like it should be really simple, but I'm struggling...can anyone help me out? Thanks!

**Edit** Sorry folks, should have said - the file is in a subfolder like so:

`www.mysite.com/folder/subfolder/file.php`

The .htaccess file is in `/folder`, the URL changes to this format:

`www.mysite.com/subfolder/file`

Apologies for misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the rule you'll need to hide .php extension. This goes into your .htaccess in the DOCUMENT_ROOT directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: It works! But...it breaks my Ajax script calls! Just checked firebug, and instead of calling includes/inc_checker.php, it's calling includes/inc_checker and not returning data...Is there anyway of making it ignore the request if it's specifically asking for a PHP file? Thanks very much for this sir!

Comment: Hmm in that case you don't need external redirect. Edited my answer, pls check.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks very much for your help. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using rewrite rules for this. Apache has built-in option explicitly for doing what you're trying to do, called [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews), and that's what you should be using:

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.

Just add `Options MultiViews` to your .htaccess, and make sure that `AllowOverride` is properly configured.

Comment: `MultiViews` has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

A guess in the wild
Try

```
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```